# How to sort different Dates?

Tags: java, spring

I want to sort the list products in class Foo by different dates (creationDate, displayDate and requestDate) and return Product List. 
Do you have an efficient proposal ?

```
public class Car extend Product {

   String name;

   Date creationDate;

   Product(String name, Date creationDate){
    this.name = name;
    this.creationDate= creationDate;
   }
}

public class Bicycle extend Product {
   String name;

   Date displayDate;

   Bicycle(String name, Date displayDate){
    this.name = name;
    displayDate= displayDate;
   }


}

public class Motorcycle extend Product {
   String name;

   Date requestDate;

   Motorcycle (String name, Date requestDate;{
    this.name = name;
    requestDate=requestDate;;
   }


}
```

.

```
public class ProductConfiguration(){

   List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
   cars.add (new Car ("Jeep", new Date());

   List<Bicycle> bicycles = new ArrayList<>();
   bicycles .add (new Bicycle ("mountainbike", new Date());

   List<Motorcycle > motorcycles = new ArrayList<>();
   motorcycles.add (new Motorcycle ("motorcycles", new Date());

// getter and setter 

}
```

I want to sort the list products in class Foo by different dates (creationDate, displayDate and requestDate) and return Product List.

```
public class Foo {


  public List<Product> readData() {  
    ProductConfiguration productConfiguration = new ProductConfiguration();

    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    products.add(productConfiguration.getCars());
    products.add(productConfiguration.getBicycles());
    products.add(productConfiguration.getMotorcycles());


   public List<Product> sortProductByDate(){
      // I want to sort the list products by date (creationDate, displayDate 
         and requestDate)
         and return the Product List products

   }

  }
}
```

Comment: Design doesn't make a lot of sense. Might as well just define an `orderDate` property on the `Product` level.

Comment: If every product has an order date, then why not simply put an `orderDate` field into your `Product` class? This way you can simply sort your list.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: 
Dates have different meanings. I have updated my post

Comment: The entire example feels contrived. You want to sort a list on a property, but two thirds of the objects in that list don't have that property. You're obviously trying to achieve something, but it's not clear from your question what that is.

Answer (score 1):

As @Seelenvirtuose suggested, i would also recommond you to add a date field to your product class:

```
public class Product // alternative: create an interface which your classes can implement
{
    private String name;
    private Date date;

    public Product(String name, Date date)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    // getter / setter
}
```

Then you are able to do the following:

```
    Product bike = new Product("Bike", new Date()); // just for example. You can create a specialized class Bike with additional fields. This is just for demonstration purposes
    Product car = new Product("Car", new Date()); // see above

    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    productList.add(bike);
    productList.add(car);

    productList.sort(new Comparator<Product>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Product o1, Product o2)
        {
            return o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
        }
    });

   // after this your list is sorted by date
```